# Type convertion of negative value to char

Tags: java, unicode, character

why there is no compilation error

```
public class alpha {

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        int a=-97;
        System.out.println((char)(a));

    }
}
```

if negative integral literals are not accepted by char ??

Comment: What error would you expect? When does casting numeric types ever cause an error?